# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)'

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write

I receive this error when I post image data string in a request. This is my code:

```
let imageData : NSData!
     imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(first.image!)!
        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) 

requestObject["pimage1"] = base64String

let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)'

Can someone help me?

Comment: We can't help if you don't show what is `params`, which is where the error comes from.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing a String into `base64String` constant?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` instead of `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` here

```
let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Comment: I don't think this is where OP's error comes from (read the error message). OP doesn't show where they use the base64 string anyway.

Comment: @EricD. Dont blindly say its wrong, make it clear. What the OP trying to do is converting data to string but he is using a wrong method  `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` which will return 'NSData' not `String`, That is a possible reason for this error

Comment: That was not "blindly". But I changed my comment anyway, read the new version, it represents my thoughts a bit better.

Comment: Cool. I'm sorry if the first version of the comment looked a bit rude, it was not my intention. Thanks. :)